# Training custom classifiers using trainCascadeObjectDetector

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision, object-recognition, matlab-cvst

Is there any good documentation about training your own classifiers(with examples included) different from [this one](http://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.cascadeobjectdetectorclass.html&ei=iI9QUY29L6PC0QGQ3ICADQ&usg=AFQjCNF4snrodCNChYWSUWK7LaICz8GHzA&bvm=bv.44158598,d.dmQ) provided by MathWorks.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [tutorial on how to use trainCascadeObjectDetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html). It describes common pitfalls, and includes examples.

There is also a [graphical tool for labeling training images](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39627) on MATLAB Central, which makes preparing your training data much less painful.

By the way, the link you posted is actually the documentation for vision.CascadeObjectDetector, which uses the classifier produced by trainCascadeObjectDetector. The doc page for trainCascadeObjectDetector is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/traincascadeobjectdetector.html).

Comment: My bad, I gave the wrong link, the link you provided is the right one, but still, is the same I was talking of, so won't help.Thanks anyway.

Comment: The tool you provided is very good, so I'll upvote you for that.

Comment: You are welcome. Do you have any specific questions? Is anything missing from the tutorial? I work at Mathworks, and I have worked on trainCascadeObjectDetector.

Comment: Sorry, but my problem goes beyond programming.From my country I cannot access MathWorks directly, I'm from Cuba, so I'm using a web proxy and the examples provided there won't load that way, if you know any other sol. please let me know.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) is a very good tutorial on how to train classifiers, is not specifically for Matlab but still it is very useful.It is for OpenCV mainly.